# C++ get type key in std::unordered_set<T>

Tags: c++

I am creating a custom container which should have semantics of `std::set<T>`, but the insert order should be retained when iterating. My plan for the implementation is to store the actual objects in a `std::vector<T>` and then have a `std::unordered_map<std::hash<T>::type, size_t>` which maps from a hash of the object to the index in the storage vector. So assuming `T` was `std::string`:

```
iset<std::string> is;

is.insert("A");
is.insert("B");
is.insert("C");
```

the internal datastructures should be:

```
storage: ["A", "B", "C"]
index: {hash("A"): 0, hash("B"): 1, hash("C"): 2}
```

My initial implementation looks like this - with an obvious missing piece in the declaration of the `std::unordered_map<?, size_t>`:

```
template <typename T>
class iset {
    std::vector<T> storage;
    std::unordered_map<?, size_t> index; // What should be the key type here?


    void insert(T&& value) {
        auto key = std::hash<T>{}(value);
        if (this->index.count(key) == 0) {
            this->index.insert( std::make_pair(key, this->storeage.size()));
            this->storage.push_back(std::move(value));
        }  
    }
}
```

I have tried various things like: `decltype( std::hash<T>() )` but currently no success. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Maybe `T`? Your question isn't very clear honestly

Comment: Return value of `std::hash::operator()` is of type `size_t`. Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/zGYb4HflHe5JgIAb.

Comment: Since your unordered map "maps from the `T` value to the storage index in the vector", then it's rather obvious that your type is `T`. Because that's what the unordered map's key does. That's what the unordered map "maps from".

Comment: how big is this container expected to get?

Comment: What if two inserted values (two strings in your case) will yield the same hash value?

Comment: It probably should be just T. The only downside with this model is you end up with two copies of T. That's fine if T is small, or the list is small, but if T is larger, it may be preferable to have just 1 copy and a reference. One option might be to build your vector as iterators into the map?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The way the question is asked I guess OP doesn't want to copy the inserted `value`. But it's only my assumption.

Comment: What was the OP planning to do if two different keys end up having the same hash value? This whole design is fundamentally broken.

Comment: OK - it started out as an attempt to avoid duplicating of the T objects, I must admit I had forgot about the problem when two objects hash to the same key - so I'll probably just forget the whole thing.

Comment: I see this "let's make a set which retains the insertion order" thing over and over again. About 99.86 times out of 100, it's a design error. Why do you need such a thing?

Comment: I am writing an application which reads one particular archaic file format - performs simulations - and outputs another equally archaic file format. In the process I need to keep track of the insert order of objects[1], and this was one - probably not very successful attempt.

[1]: It's more complicated than "just a vector :-)"

Comment: Moving this here: You can use `decltype(std::hash<T>{}(std::declval<T>()))` to get it generically, but all `std::hash::operator()` return `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Question is answered in comments - but the whole approach was judged fundamentally broken and I'll just forget about it.

Comment: Maybe, you should have asked a different way. For example, **How to solve a problem of storing some complex objects in a container without duplicities while maintaining their insertion order, avoiding their copying, and enabling fast lookup?** As far as I understand, this is what you really want.

Comment: Yes - that might have been better; I was probably to focused on my own broken approach. Sounds like you have a good answer to the better question?

Comment: Actually, I don't, but, generally, it's quite an interesting problem. You might consider asking a new separate question about it.

Comment: My initial thought is to store objects in a `std::deque`, which does not reallocate during insertions and maintains order. And then, use some "indexing" above it. You might use objects' hashes as keys for fast lookup, but then, for each such a key, you need to store generally multiple pointers/iterators into a deque.

Comment: I just created some exemplary code for you: https://wandbox.org/permlink/n8AdGWrJUcktlN2i. For higher efficiency, it should be better to store pointers into deque instead of indexes. And, I did not care about possible exceptions. The drawback is that you need a dynamic memory allocations (vectors) just to prevent possible (and maybe very unlikely) hash collisions. Some small-buffer-optimization-enabled vector may help here quite a lot, e.g., `boost::container::small_vector`.

Comment: Thanks - the example was interesting - both the use `std::deque<T>` which is not the first tool in my chest - and the need for a vector of indices to protect agains collisions. I'll probably start off with your example - thank you!